# Is there a kendo.all.min.js file in kendo webjars

Tags: kendo-ui, webjars

Is there a file call kendo.all.min.js in kendo webjar?

If not, what's the equivalent?

I really don't want to import kendo js file one by one to my html page.

Comment: You should file an issue on the project: https://github.com/webjars/kendo-ui-core

Comment: I found the lasted version on maven is 2016, how come this project is still showing version 2014? are you sure this is the repo?

Comment: Maybe you are seeing the NPM or Bower WebJar which is deployed from http://webjars.org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no kendo.all.min.js file in kendo webjars, I believe the main concern might be license.